# why apparmor_parser process using such high CPU and how to stop it

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, apparmor

I have Ubuntu 21.04 installed on raspberry pi. Whole system is getting hanged so checked usage. And strangely **apparmor_parser** using almost 100% CPU.

[image]

I tried killing this process like below

```
Kill -s SIGKILL 3803
```

But it is not going anywhere.

Tried stopping apparmor and disabling it like below, but still that process is there

```
sudo systemctl stop apparmor
sudo systemctl disable apparmor
```

What should I try next???